# Shooting Method- Boundary value problem starting from -1 to 1

Tags: matlab

The equation is $\rho \frac{d \bar{u}}{dy} = -\frac{d\bar{p}}{dx} + \mu\frac{d^2\bar{u}}{dy^2} $

with boundary condition

$u(-1)=0$ and $u(1)=1$

I am to solve it using fifth order runge-kutta felhberg approach with Matlab. To do that, I have to change the equation to initial value problem using shooting method.

So, my problems are:

1. how can I do that when the boundary is from -1
2. Please I need the matlab code to do it.
   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to use RKF (Runge–Kutta–Fehlber​g), you need to transform your second order ODE into a first order one as:

$$\bar{u}^{'} = \bar{v}$$

$$\mu \bar{v}^{'} = \bar{p}^{'} + \rho \bar{v}$$

With boundary conditions: $\bar{u}|_{y=-1} = 0$ and $\bar{u}|_{y=1} = 1$.

In order to use shooting method you need to convert this boundary value problem (BVP) into an initial value problem (IVP) by replacing the second boundary condition ($\bar{u}|_{y=1} = 1$) with this one: $\bar{u}^{'}|_{y=-1} = a$, where $a $ is a unknown constant parameter here. Now, let's define this function:

$$F(a) = \bar{u}_{1}|_{y=1}(a) - \bar{u}|_{y=1}$$

Where $\bar{u}_{1}|_{y=1}(a)$ is the value of function obtained by solving IVP at $y=1$ and $\bar{u}|_{y=1}$ is the boundary condition of BVP above. If you find the root of $F(a)$, you will end up to having to finding that specific $a$ which would satisfy the second boundary condition, but that's what you want here as a solution for your BVP that started with it. In fact you solve the IVP by using RKF and then will find the root of $F(a)$ by some standard root finding methods such as Newton-Raphson or Bisection.

**Update:**

It's a Python implementation:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import bisect
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 1
rho = 1
u_b = 1

def p_prime(y):
    return y

# function that returns dz/dt
def model(w,y):
    dvdt = p_prime(y) / mu + (rho / mu) * w[1]
    dudt = w[1]
    dwdt = [dudt,dvdt]
    return dwdt

def problem(a):

# initial condition
    w0 = [0,a]

# time points
    y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)

# solve ODE
    w = odeint(model,w0,y)

    return w

a = np.linspace(0,1,10)

y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)

for av in a:

    w = problem(av)

    # plot results
    plt.plot(y,w[:,0],label=r'u'+' ,a = '+str(av))
    #plt.plot(y,w[:,1],'r--',label=r'v')
plt.ylabel('u')
plt.xlabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()

def F(a):

    w = problem(a)

    return (w[y.shape[0]-1,0] - u_b)

a = np.linspace(0,1,100)

Fs = []

for av in a:
    Fs.append(F(av))

# plot results
plt.plot(a,Fs)
plt.ylabel('F(a)')
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.show()

a_star = bisect(F,0,1)

print "The root of F(a): " + str(bisect(F,0,1))

w = problem(a_star)

# plot results
plt.plot(y,w[:,0],'b-',label=r'u'+' ,a = '+str(a_star))
plt.plot(y,w[:,1],'r--',label=r'v'+' ,a = '+str(a_star))
plt.ylabel('w')
plt.xlabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

and these are outputs for $\bar{u}$ at different $a$ values, the variation of $F(a)$ at various $a$ values, and finally the $a^{*}$ which is the root of $F(a)$ and final result based on $a^{*}$:

```py
The root of F(a): 0.469552906694
```

[image]

[image]

[image]